# Is recording to wav file with Qt6 supported on Windows?

Tags: qt, audio, wav, qt6, qmediarecorder

I am trying to record audio to wav file on Windows using `QMediaRecorder` in Qt6.

Printing supported formats doesn't list Wave:

```
QMediaFormat format;
qDebug() << format.supportedFileFormats(QMediaFormat::ConversionMode::Encode);
```

> QList(QMediaFormat::Mpeg4Audio, QMediaFormat::FLAC,
> QMediaFormat::MPEG4, QMediaFormat::WMV, QMediaFormat::AAC,
> QMediaFormat::MP3, QMediaFormat::WMA)

Is this a known issue for Qt6, since it worked with Qt5?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure WAV codec is really installed on your system? Another Qt user [has the same problem](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-109662) with the WAV codec on Windows 11. [Mitch Curtis](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-109662#comment-698749) points to [Microsoft Codecs FAQ](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/codecs-faq-392483a0-b9ac-27c7-0f61-5a7f18d408af) that explains "how to find out which codecs are installed on your computer":

- On the **Help** menu in Windows Media Player, select **About Windows Media
  Player**. If you don't see the **Help** menu, select **Organize > Layout >
  Show menu bar**.
- In the **About Windows Media Player** dialog box, select **Technical Support Information**. Your web browser will open a page that includes
  a lot of detailed info about the related binary files, codecs,
  filters, plug-ins, and services installed on your PC. This info
  should help you troubleshoot problems.